# how to go back to the preview state after using setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using setState to sort an array by name. I was asked to create a button to do this and I did. However, I need to implement a functionally that when I click that button again after the array is sorted to go back to the previews state. The unorder array.

this is my code:

```
export class MoviesIndexContainer extends Component {

   
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(this.props.movies.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.title.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    var nameB = b.title.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
    }

    // names must be equal
    return 0;
    }))
   
    console.log('Se hizo click');
  };
   
  

    componentDidMount() {
     this.props.DispatchfetchMovies();
    }

    render(){
        if (this.props.loadingState === 'notStarted'){
            return null
        }
        return (
            <>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="inline-block border border-blue-500 rounded py-2 px-3 mt-6 bg-blue-500 text-white mx-0.5">Sort By Name</button>
                <section className="max-w-6xl w-11/12 mx-auto mt-16">
                { this.props.loadingState === 'inProgress' ? (
                    'loading content') : (
                    <MovieList movies={this.props.movies}/>
                    
                    )} 
                </section>
          </> 
        )
    
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me on how to implement this? I'm new to react and this is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it sounds like you are trying to have the appearance of a sorted array, but need to preserve the initial configuration. There are more than a few ways to achieve this behaviour.

Probably the easiest is to sort a copy of the list and pass that to the `MovieList` component. Determine if the list should be sorted or not based on button press by keeping track of a boolean value in State.

```
// Don't forget to include any CSS necessary to display your App
import React from "react";


class MovieList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.movies.map((m, i) => <li key={i}>{m.title}</li>)}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

class MoviesIndexContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isSorted: false
    };

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({isSorted: !this.state.isSorted});
    };


    render() {
        if (this.props.loadingState === 'notStarted') {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}
                        className="inline-block border border-blue-500 rounded py-2 px-3 mt-6 bg-blue-500 text-white mx-0.5">Sort
                    By Name
                </button>
                <section className="max-w-6xl w-11/12 mx-auto mt-16">
                    {this.props.loadingState === 'inProgress' ? (
                        'loading content') : (
                        this.state.isSorted ?
                            <MovieList movies={[...this.props.movies].sort((a, b) => {
                                return a.title.localeCompare(b.title, undefined, {sensitivity: 'accent'})
                            })}/> : <MovieList movies={this.props.movies}/>

                    )}
                </section>
            </>
        )

    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MoviesIndexContainer movies={[{title: "Thunder Force"}, {title: "concrete Cowboy"},
                {title: 'Godzilla vs Kong'}, {title: 'Justice League'}]}
                                  loadingState={'Done'}/>)
    }
}

export default App;
```